# implement captcha in theme (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, themes, captcha

First of all, thank you in advance for your help.

I'm having a problem because i was never told to do this before.

I have a wordpress with a theme that has his own registration/login form. The past week we were experiencing login attacks and stuff, so i want to implement a captcha for the login form.

The problem is, how i can implement a captcha directly into the theme and make it work? I was having a look here and apparently nobody had this problem.

Thank you guys again and maybe sorry for the obbious question... i'm kinda noob in this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end i found the solution.

The "problem" was that WooCommerce was the one that was "hosting" this login form. So i installed the plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-captcha-recaptcha-for-woocommerce/

And now everything works as expected.

Than you for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Install this plugin :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/captcha/

- Upload the captcha folder to the /wp-content/plugins/ directory.
- Activate the plugin via the 'Plugins' menu in WordPress.
- Plugin settings are located in "BWS Plugins" > "Captcha".
- That's it !

Comment: Thanks for your answer daniyalahmad!

But as i said, i have a custom page for the login form (included with the template), so this form is not changing. As i understand i should edit manually, but don't know where to start.